# What software should I use to graph this? / How do I get rearrange this equation so that it is in terms of y?

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

I thought I'd just quickly tell you guys why I want to graph this equation before giving it you.

We're studying conic sections at the moment, and I started wondering what would happen if I let the directrix be a parabola. I looked at the instance where the directrix is y=x^2. I let the focus, F, be (x_F,y_F). Let P=(x,y) be a point on the curve that I am trying to find. I was wondering what the equation of this curve would be if I said that the distance between P and F and the perpendicular distance between P and the directrix has to be the same for any point P. ie. if we let O be the point where P meets the directrix at right angles, then OP=PF. I shall let O=(x_1,y_1)

The gradient of the directrix at point O has to 2(x_1). Thus the gradient of OP has to be (-1/(2(x_1))). Thus, we can represent O as (x+t, y-(t/(2(x_1))), where t is an unknown variable. Since x_1=x+t, we can further represent O as (x+t, y-(t/(2(x+t))). Substituting these values for x_1 and y_1 back into our equation for the directrix, we get:

y-(t/(2(x+t))=(x+t)^2

I let u=x+t, now:
y-(u-x)/(2u)=u^2
=> 2uy-(u-x)=u^3
=> u^3+(1-2y)u-x=0

I then solve this cubic using Cardano's method (method in the link below)
http://www.math.cornell.edu/~henderson/courses/M403-S03/cubics.htm

I get u=(((x/2)+((x/2)^2+((1-2y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))+(((x/2)-((x/2)^2+((1-2y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))
thus t=(((x/2)+((x/2)^2+((1-2y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))+(((x/2)-((x/2)^2+((1-2y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))-x

I want to show that OP=PF. (PF)^2= (x_F-x)^2 + (y_F-y)^2,
and (OP)^2 = (y-y_1)^2 + (x-x_1)^2 = (t/(2(x+t)))^2 + t^2

Thus, replacing t in terms of x and y we get:
(((((x/2)+((x/2)^2+((1-2*y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))+(((x/2)-((x/2)^2+((1-2*y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))-x)^2)*((((x/2)+((x/2)^2+((1-2*y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))+(((x/2)-((x/2)^2+((1-2*y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))+1)/(4*((((x/2)+((x/2) ^2+(1-2*y)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))+(((x/2)-((x/2)^2+(1-2*y)^3)^0.5)^(1/3)))^2)-(x_F-x)^2-(y_F-y)^2 = 0

(easier to see equation)
[image: easier to see equation]

This is the function that I want to plot. I'm just interested to see what it'd look like. Of course I'd have to replace x_F and y_F with set values. I just want to know if any of you know of software which can plot this equation. I don't want to plot a 3-D graph though, unless I am able to set the value of z to 0.

OR

If you guys know of a way to rearrange this equation so that y becomes the subject, then I can simply use any graphing software to plot the curve.

Comment: "(t/(2(x+t))^2 + t^2" has unbalanced parentheses.  I wish I could see the system of equations from which you wish to eliminate $t$, but piecing it together from this explanation is not straightforward.

Comment: fixed it now, thanks for the heads up

Comment: I've already eliminated t. I eliminated it when I solved the cubic u^3+(1-2y)-x=0, where u=x+t, I then subtracted x from this value of u. This leaves me with t. I substituted this value of t into (t/(2(x+t)))^2 + t^2, which is the length of OP, since x_1=x+t, => x_1-x=t, and similarly y_1-y= (t/(2(x+t))). the length of OP^2 is (x_1-x)^2 + (y_1-y)^2. Thus I get my length of OP. This has to equal PF, and thus I get my final equation by substituting t in terms of x and y.

Comment: WHat do you mean by "the system of equations from which you wish to eliminate t"? We may be thinking different things.

Comment: Either way, I'm more interested in finding some software to plot this equation :P Or to simplify the equation so that it is in terms of y so I can then plot it.

Comment: It was trivial to solve for $y$ before your manipulation to solve for $u$ in terms of $x$.  If I could figure out what you intend to eliminate $t$ against, I'd start there, not with the hopeless mess you got after Cardano.

Comment: I wanted to express t in terms of x and y. That was my goal, and I achieved it. The result of this is I have a final equation for x and y. My final equation is the equation for the curve that heropup put below, however he expressed it parametrically. I'm still not sure what you mean by "intend to eliminate t against". I know the question has already been solved, but I'd be interested to know what exactly you think I did wrong. I agree that it's messy, but I did end up with a final equation for my curve. I wouldn't exactly call it "hopeless".

Comment: See here: I manage to express t in terms of x and y: t=(((x/2)+((x/2)^2+((1-2y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))+(((x/2)-((x/2)^2+((1-2y)/3)^3)^0.5)^(1/3))-x. This is what I intended to do.

Answer (score 3):

I will use somewhat different notation, for clarity.  Let $F = (p,q)$ be a "focus," and for each point $P(t) = (t,t^2)$ on the parabola $y = x^2$, suppose we are interested in the locus of points $L(p,q,t)$ such that $PL = LF$ where $PL$ is normal to the parabola.  This is a complicated curve, but it can be parametrized as $$L(p,q,t) = \left(\frac{p^2 t+q^2 t-2 q t^3-q t+t^5}{2 p t-q-t^2},\frac{-p^2+4 p t^3+2 pt-q^2-3 t^4-t^2}{2 \left(2 p t-q-t^2\right)}\right).$$  Note that this requires $t^2-2pt + q \ne 0$.

We can use *Mathematica* to draw an interactive plot of this locus:

```
F[p_,q_,t_] := {(p^2 t - q t + q^2 t - 2 q t^3 + t^5)/(-q + 2 p t - t^2),
       (p^2 + q^2 - 2 p t + t^2 - 4 p t^3 + 3 t^4)/(2 (q - 2 p t + t^2))}
Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot[{F[p, q, t], {t, t^2}}, {t, -3, 3}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}}, Exclusions -> {t^2 == 2 p t - q}],
    Graphics[{Disk[{p, q}, .05], Line[{{m, m^2}, F[p, q, m], {p, q}}]}]],
    {{p, -1}, -3, 3}, {{q, 2}, -3, 3}, {{m, 0}, -3, 3}]
```

which gives, for instance, the following:

[image]

Here is a picture for varying $p$:

[image]

Comment: THANKS MAN, this is exactly what I was looking for :D I think I'll use mathematica from now on for these kinds of things. Btw, I didn't know how to change how my notation looks, so that's partly why it's so messy :P I see that you looked at a point on the parabola rather than the curve trying to be created, that was probably the wiser choice. anyways, thanks for the answer! I'd vote you up if I had the reputation :P

Comment: Impressive work, especially given that it was done in about 30 minutes.

Comment: Out of interest, how did you parametrize L(p,q,t)?

Comment: The normal line at $P(t) = (t,t^2)$ is given by $y = f(x) = \frac{t-x}{2t} + t^2$. Then we solve for $x$ such that $(x-t)^2 + (f(x)-t^2)^2 = PL^2 = LF^2 = (x-p)^2 + (f(x)-q)^2$.  This gives $x$ as a function of $p, q, t$, hence $y = f(x)$ and finally $L(p,q,t) = (x(p,q,t), y(p,q,t))$.  One could do the calculations by hand, but since I wanted to make an animation, *Mathematica* was more convenient.